# How do I parse the XML tag <m:properties> for my Android application using Java?

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to display Quote Date, Rate Type and Rate.
I am using Nodes, but I am not sure if it is an element or an attribute, it may be a namespace, not sure how to reference that.

this is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">DailyTreasuryLongTermRateData</title>
  <id>http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryLongTermRateData</id>
  <updated>2016-04-16T00:05:04Z</updated>
  <link rel="self" title="DailyTreasuryLongTermRateData" href="DailyTreasuryLongTermRateData" />
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryLongTermRateData(11440)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2016-04-16T00:05:04Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryLongTermRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryLongTermRateData(11440)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryLongTermRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">11440</d:Id>
        <d:QUOTE_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2015-04-01T00:00:00</d:QUOTE_DATE>
        <d:EXTRAPOLATION_FACTOR>N/A</d:EXTRAPOLATION_FACTOR>
        <d:RATE_TYPE>BC_20year</d:RATE_TYPE>
        <d:RATE m:type="Edm.Double">2.23</d:RATE>
      </m:properties>
    </content>`enter code here`
```

this is my code so far:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = null;
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
        try {
            documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(result));
            doc = documentBuilder.parse(is);
            doc.normalize();


            Node rootNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
            String rootNodeName = rootNode.getNodeName();
            tvNodeName.setText(rootNodeName);

            NodeList nlProperties = doc.getElementsByTagName("d:");
            Node nProperties = nlProperties.item(0);
            Node nPropertiesText = nProperties.getFirstChild();
            tvQuoteDate.setText(nPropertiesText.getNodeValue());

            NodeList nlPoint = doc.getElementsByTagName("d:");
            Node nPoint = nlPoint.item(0);
            NamedNodeMap nnm = nPoint.getAttributes();

            Node rateType, rate;
            rateType = nnm.getNamedItem("RATE_TYPE");
            rate = nnm.getNamedItem("RATE");

            tvRateType.setText(rateType.getNodeValue());
            tvRate.setText(rate.getNodeValue());


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Simple - XML 3rd party library.

```
http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php.
```

Check their second page there is a tutorial and code snippets.

You can use "m" as prefix and it will add it the "m" before the properties.

this is taken from their tutorial page, make sure you read it there!:

```
@Namespace(reference="your refrence", prefix="m")
```

---

To make your life a bit more easier you can also try [converting_xml_to_pojo](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) websites and it will create for you classes automatically, you will just need to copy pase and add the elements/attributes additional info such as @Element, @Attribute, etc as mentioned in their tutorial